# Pass outfile FILE_PATH as parameter when exporting CSV from MySQL query

Tags: mysql, export-to-csv, select-into-outfile

How do I pass the outfile file path to MySQL? I have tried the below. It does not work.

My SQL file

```
SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT *
FROM
     `registered_user`
INTO OUTFILE ',@output_location,' FIELDS TERMINATED BY \',\'
LINES TERMINATED BY \'\n\'');

PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
      EXECUTE stmt;
      DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

My command-line command

```
mysql -u root -p test -e "set @output_location= '/var/tmp/out.csv'; source test2.sql;"
```

I get the below error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '/var/tmp/out.csv FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '
'' at line 12
```

It works if I give only `out.csv`. But I don't know where the file is stored. Am I missing any escape sequence in the above command?

[This problem](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=13870) has been reported to MySQL. But has there been a solution?

Comment: Include `select @query;` after `PREPARE stmt FROM @query;` and share the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply debug by selecting the query like `select @query` how it was framed.

On `concat` Try double quotes `"` instead of single quotes `'` when you have quotes inside. This will avoid missing `'` which you have right now. And don't forget to escape `\n` when `concat` like `\\n`

```
SET @query = CONCAT("SELECT *
FROM
     `registered_user`
INTO OUTFILE '",@output_location,"'  -- you need to enclose path with quotes
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'");

PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: thanks you but The query is fine. It works when i hardcode the path. I am unable to figure out how to pass the file path from commandline. I have edited the question with a link. Hope it clarifies my question

Comment: This works. Don't know y question was down voted though. Anyways Thanks @James